# Update ProgressView after the view controller has been changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I currently have a progress view which shows the current amount of how much of a file has been downloaded so far. When the user clicks the download button the progress succesfully updates and when they leave the view controller and return to it **while it is still downloading** the progress still updates successfuly. However my problem is when the download finishes and the user has left and returned to the view the progress view no longer responds to any updates. I have did some research into multi-threading and seen that many people suggest to do any UI updates in the main thread like so:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(progressUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

So I tried it in my code and the still got the same results (once the user leaves and returns to the view controller after the download has finished the progress view does not respond to any updates). I then added a NSLog to see if the method was being called and the debugger outputted the NSLog. So what is going on? Here is the code for the view controller:

## VideoTest.m

```
#import "VideoTest.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FileDownloadInfo.h"


@interface VideoTest ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrFileDownloadData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *docDirectoryURL;

-(void)initializeFileDownloadDataArray;
-(int)getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:(unsigned long)taskIdentifier;

@end

@implementation VideoTest{

NSString *url;

}

@synthesize moviePlayer;
@synthesize download;
@synthesize videoAlreadyPlaying, progressView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    
    // Custom initialization

}
return self;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];
//Setting video URl
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
url = @"http://therosary.info/AppVideos/TheChaplet/Information%20on%20Divine%20Mercy.mp4";

//selectors set
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    
//Play the movie
videoAlreadyPlaying=@"TRUE";
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,64,320,220);
[moviePlayer play];

[self initializeFileDownloadDataArray];

NSArray *URLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
self.docDirectoryURL = [URLs objectAtIndex:0];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.jjdoherty98.Marion_s_Net"];
sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 5;


self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration
                                             delegate:self
                                        delegateQueue:nil];


if([appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading isEqual:@"FALSE"] || appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading==nil){
    self.progressView.hidden = YES;
    progressView.progress=0;
}
if([appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading isEqual:@"TRUE"]){
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(progressUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


}

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController || self.isBeingDismissed) {
    NSLog(@"Left View");
    [moviePlayer stop];

}
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

AppDelegate *mainDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
mainDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = @"TRUE";
return YES;

}


- (void)MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
{ //playing
    videoAlreadyPlaying = @"TRUE";
}
if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
{ //stopped
}if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
{ //paused
}if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted)
{ //interrupted
}if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward)
{ //seeking forward
    
}if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward)
{ //seeking backward
}

}



- (void)willEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSLog(@"willEnterFullscreen");
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = @"TRUE";
}

- (void)enteredFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSLog(@"enteredFullscreen");


}

- (void)willExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSLog(@"willExitFullscreen");
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = @"FALSE";

}

- (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSLog(@"exitedFullscreen");
if(appDelegate.CurrentProgress==0){
    progressView.hidden=TRUE;
}else{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(progressUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
}

- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSNumber* reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
switch ([reason intValue]) {
    case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
        NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Ended");
        videoAlreadyPlaying=@"FALSE";
        [moviePlayer stop];
        [moviePlayer play];
        break;
        
    case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
        NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Error");
        videoAlreadyPlaying=@"FALSE";
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video Failed To Load!"
                                                        message:@"Unable to connect to server, please try again later!"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        break;
        
    case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
        NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: User Exited");
        videoAlreadyPlaying=@"FALSE";

        break;
        
    default:
        break;
        
}

[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];

}


-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if([appDelegate.isThereInternet isEqual:@"TRUE"]){
if([appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading  isEqual: @"FALSE"]){
//If there is internet and not already downloading
    progressView.hidden=FALSE;
    progressView.progress=0;
    FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:0];
    fdi.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fdi.downloadSource]];
    fdi.taskIdentifier = fdi.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;
    // Start the task.
    [fdi.downloadTask resume];
    
}}
if ([appDelegate.isThereInternet isEqual:@"FALSE"]) {
    //No internet available
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unable to connect to server"
                                                    message:@"Internet connection appears to be offline, please try again later!"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    
}
    if([appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading isEqual:@"TRUE"]){
    //Is already downloaing
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File Already Downloading"
                                                    message:@"Multiple files can not be downloaded at the same time!"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    
}

}

-(void)initializeFileDownloadDataArray{
self.arrFileDownloadData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:[[FileDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:nil andDownloadSource:url]];
}


-(int)getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:(unsigned long)taskIdentifier{
int index = 0;
for (int i=0; i<[self.arrFileDownloadData count]; i++) {
    FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:i];
    if (fdi.taskIdentifier == taskIdentifier) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
 }

return index;
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *destinationFilename = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.lastPathComponent;
NSURL *destinationURL = [self.docDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:destinationFilename];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationURL path]]) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:nil];
}

BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location
                                    toURL:destinationURL
                                    error:&error];

if (success) {
    int index = [self getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:downloadTask.taskIdentifier];
    FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:index];
    
    fdi.isDownloading = NO;
    fdi.downloadComplete = YES;
    
    // Set the initial value to the taskIdentifier property of the fdi object,
    // so when the start button gets tapped again to start over the file download.
    fdi.taskIdentifier = -1;
    
    // In case there is any resume data stored in the fdi object, just make it nil.
    fdi.taskResumeData = nil;
 
    
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Unable to copy temp file. Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Download completed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading=@"FALSE";
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to download!"
                                                    message:@"Unable to connect to the server!"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    });

}
else{
    appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading=@"FALSE";
    NSLog(@"Download finished successfully.");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:0];
        fdi.isDownloading = NO;
        fdi.downloadComplete = YES;
        fdi.taskIdentifier = -1;
        fdi.taskResumeData = nil;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download Complete!"
                                                        message:@"Go to downloads section to view the file now!"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    });
    
    
}
}



-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

if (totalBytesExpectedToWrite == NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown) {
    NSLog(@"Unknown transfer size");
}
else{
    int index = [self getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:downloadTask.taskIdentifier];
    FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:index];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading=@"TRUE";
        fdi.downloadProgress = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
        appDelegate.CurrentProgress = fdi.downloadProgress;
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(progressUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}
}


-(void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

[self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
    
    if ([downloadTasks count] == 0) {
        if (appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler != nil) {
            
            // Make nil the backgroundTransferCompletionHandler.
            appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler = nil;
            progressView.hidden=TRUE;
            
                // Show a local notification when all downloads are over.
                UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                localNotification.alertBody = @"All files have been downloaded!";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
         
        }
    }
}];
}

-(void)progressUpdate{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if ([appDelegate.isAlreadyDownloading isEqual:@"TRUE"]) {
    progressView.progress = appDelegate.CurrentProgress;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(progressUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    NSLog(@"Is this method being called");
    if (appDelegate.CurrentProgress==1) {
        progressView.hidden=TRUE;
    }
}

}
@end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like all the action depends on the viewDidLoad firing.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Why should a view continue updating when the download has already finished?

Comment: @Mundi So i can reset the progress back to zero and what if the user clicks the download button again?

Comment: @danh if that is what it takes to fix the problem then yes. This problem has been driving me mad for the past couple of days

Comment: I know this does not solve the issue but I just switched over to AFNetworking instead and followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273987/afnetworking-restore-progress-bar-after-view-reopened/24274853#24274853 and now the problem no longer occurs